# Java - the inherited method com.example.project.ConcreteA cannot hide the abstract method in com.example.project.MyInterface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, access-modifiers

For some reason, I can't declare a method in an Interface as package-only; it automatically declares as public. Here is the simplified code:

```
package com.example.project;

public interface MyInterface {

    void foo();
    Thing bar(); // The class Thing is in the com.example.project package, but what it does isn't important.

}



package com.example.project;

public abstract class SimpleConcrete implements MyInterface { // Initializes all methods as hooks
    
    protected Thing bar = new Thing();
    
    void foo() {}
    Thing bar() { return bar }
    
}
    


package com.example.project;

public class ConcreteA extends SimpleConcrete {
    
    void bar() {
        // code here...
    }
    
}



package com.example.project;

public class ConcreteB extends SimpleConcrete {
    
    void bar() {
        // more code here...
    }
    
}
```

When I try to compile this, these errors come, all connected:

> **File:** C:\ProjectFolder\com\example\project\SimpleConcrete.java  [line: 7]
>
> **Error:** Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from me.mathmaniac.everworlds.Block
>
> **File:** C:\ProjectFolder\com\example\project\ConcreteA.java  [line: 3]
>
> **Error:** The inherited method com.example.project.SimpleConcrete.foo() cannot hide the public abstract method in com.example.project.MyInterface
>
> **File:** C:\ProjectFolder\com\example\project\ConcreteB.java  [line: 3]
>
> **Error:** The inherited method com.example.project.SimpleConcrete.foo() cannot hide the public abstract method in com.example.project.MyInterface

Does anybody know how to fix this, or do I have to keep my Interfaces public to the whole Java code, not just open to the package?
For security reasons, I want to keep the methods open only to the package, but it needed, I will try to find how to solve the problem another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods declared in an interface are [implicitly `public`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html).

> All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly `public`, so you can omit the `public` modifier.

To have any other access modifier on the method, you must convert the interface to an `abstract` class, and convert the method to an `abstract` method.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad that it can't be an interface, OOP and all that.

Answer (score 3):

All methods within an interface in Java are implicitly public. See here for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

You could make the interface package level by declaring it like this:

```
interface MyInterface {

    void foo();
    Thing bar();
}
```

This would at least keep it encapsulated within that package.

Comment: @MathManiac Not sure I understand you correctly. You said you wanted to keep the methods accessible to the package only. My suggested solution achieves this.